# How to use exportAs in Angular 5 on directives to get its reference in the template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have the below directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[changeColor]',
  exportAs:'changeColor' 
})
export class ColorDirective {
    constructor(elem: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
       renderer.setStyle(elem.nativeElement, 'color', 'red');
    }
}
```

I have the below template:

```
<h1 changeColor>Hello</h1>
```

This works as expected and displays "Hello" in red. But, when I try to access a reference of the directive I get an error. For example, the below code:

```
<h1 #x=changeColor>Hello</h1>
{{x}}
```

produces the below error `"There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "changeColor""`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whether you imported directive in AppModule or in any feature module?

Comment: Yes. It is part of my app.module.ts declaration. That is why it was working till I used a template variable.

Comment: #x="changeColor" try to give inside " codes ". It should work.

Comment: Well, you didn't apply the changeColor directive in the second snippet, since there is no `changeColor` attribute on the h1. `<h1 changeColor #x="changeColor">Hello</h1>`.

Comment: @JBNizet, Oh! I totally missed it! Thanks! If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Also, if possible, can you explain why the selector of an attribute should be within [ ] in your answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't apply the `changeColor` directive in the second snippet, since there is no `changeColor` attribute on the `h1`. It should be

```
<h1 changeColor #x="changeColor">Hello</h1>
```

> can you explain why the selector of an attribute should be within [ ]

Because that's the syntax for CSS selectors (the same you're using in a CSS stylesheet):

- `[foo]` selects any element with an attribute named foo
- `.foo` selects any element with a CSS class named foo
- `foo` selects any element named foo
- `bar[foo]:not(.baz)` selects any element named bar, which has an attribute named foo and doesn't have a class named baz.