# routerLinkActive route for child and parent

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I am trying to apply or highlight navigation routes for my menu bar with below code, what i could get is, i could able to highlight the submenu, but could not able to highlight the parent menu bar.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a
                        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" style="color: white; cursor: pointer;"
                        [routerLinkActive]="['class1']">Parent</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left"
                            aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                                [routerLink]="['app-child1']"
                                [routerLinkActive]="['class1']"
                                >Child 1</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                                [routerLink]="['app-child2']"
                                [routerLinkActive]="['class1']"
                                >Child 2</a>
                        </div>
</li>
```

Css class:

```
.class1{
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

Comment: where do you apply the `class1` class?

Comment: you could check against the active route? then apply the class acordingly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use template reference variable (`#`) to get reference to`routerLinkActive` and its properties and then use `isActive`.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
        id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
        data-toggle="dropdown" 
        style="color: white; cursor: pointer;"
        [ngClass]="{'class1': child1RLA.isActive || child2RLA.isActive}">  <!-- <-- Check if child routes are active -->
            Parent
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left"
        aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                [routerLink]="['app-child1']"
                [routerLinkActive]="['class1']"
                #child1RLA="routerLinkActive">          <!-- <-- Assign routerLinkActive reference to child1RLA variable -->
                    Child 1
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" 
                    [routerLink]="['app-child2']"
                    [routerLinkActive]="['class1']"
                    #child2RLA="routerLinkActive">      <!-- <-- Assign routerLinkActive reference to child2RLA variable -->
                        Child 2
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What? It is not "angular id". It is template reference variable. How can you use `exportAs` of directives then? And how can I use this exact method in my project then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746274/how-to-use-exportas-in-angular-5-on-directives-to-get-its-reference-in-the-templ

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/handle-template-reference-variables-with-directives-223081bc70c2

Comment: its not a directive? and probably for the same reason people use jquery in angular projects. just because you *can* do something, doesnt mean you *should*

Comment: What do you mean by "not a directive"? [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) is a **directive** and it has **exportAs:  'routerLinkActive'** which you can use to access its directive-specific properties. Read the [examples](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description) in official docs.

Comment: i never said `RouterLinkActive` wasnt a directive, i said that `#.....` isnt a directive, its an identifier

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? I said:  It is not "angular id". It is template reference variable. When did I say `#...` is a directive. It is a reference to directive. I kindly ask you to revoke the downvote because you are **totally wrong** in this situation. What I offer in the answer is a **%100 valid usage**.

Comment: but as `#...` cant be duplicated within the same html file, it is therefore also a valid identifier. how are you certain that i am the downvoter? and if you read the tooltip, voting is for usefulness, not for whether the answer is believed to be correct or not

Comment: It is not duplicated. Are `#child1RLA` and `#child2RLA` duplicated? For usefulness, I already use this method to structure my main menu in my projects. Whatever... I'm done with this conversation.

Comment: i didnt say that they are duplicated, i just said that they cant be duplicated hence they are also validly used as identifiers. and to me, its people like you who ruin it because of bad answers

Answer (score 15):

To highlight a side menu link just add routerLinkActive="cssClassName" to the anchor elements like:

```
<a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="cssClassName">Profile</a>
<a routerLink="/profile/details" routerLinkActive="cssClassName">Profile Details</a>
```

this will highlight both links if route becomes /profile or /profile/details 
If you don't want to hightlight parent route when user selects profile details in this case, then just add an additional attribute to parent route i.e. 'routerLinkActiveOptions' as follows:

```
<a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="cssClassName"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Profile</a>
```

This is the simple way to highlight side menu links when the become activated.

Answer (score 4):

just put the routerLinkActive on the parent element, as described here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
  <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `routerLinkActive` to apply the class for the active routes.

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Dashboard</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).